# why do my gladiolus corms get smaller every year and then die

Tags: gladiolus

My "Mon Amour" gladiolus corms get smaller every year and eventually die.  My "Jester" and "Priscilla" corms seem to do well.  Why do the Mon Amour corms fail to thrive?